# Setting up an If Else Statement loop in Unity for Particle Systems

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scripting

I just started using Unity 2 days ago. I've created 4 Particle Systems in Unity that I'm trying to animate over a planet that I've created but I want to make each particle system to be active for 10-20 seconds depending on a .txt file from an outside source. Does anyone have any idea how to go about this?

Kinda of like this

```
if (line == 'Anger')
     #play said animation
else if (line == 'Excitement')
     #play other animation
else
     #play last animation
```

Would I have to create a script that each particle system would need to read from?

Comment: You should look in to the [Animation Controllers](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AnimatorControllers.html) built in to Unity

Answer (score 0):

### It is not that easy.

The best thing you could do is have a different object for each particle system. They are all initially disabled. Then when you want to play a particular particle style, turn on the object with the particle system that you want via

```
gameObject.SetActive(true);
```

If you want to keep them active for only a specified period of time, then use a coroutine, and after the elapsed time then disable your object to turn it off. Use world space particles to prevent all the particles from just disappearing when the object is disabled for aesthetics.

Alternatively skip the coroutine and set the particle system duration manually in the inspector, or alter it via getcomponent<>();

Quick example:

```
// Assign the game objects manually from the Unity interface via drag and drop. That is why public GameObject[].

Public GameObject[] ParticleSystems;
Private String[] YourEmotions;
float activationDuration = 15f;

// Your code to retrieve the txt value and assign to 'YourEmotions' array, or use YourEmotions = {"Angry", "Sad", "Happy"};. Have the order match the order of the equivalent game object. Then when you need the particle system, active it by calling StartParticularParticleSystem and passing in the string identifier of the one you want to use.
// ...

Public Void StartParticularParticleSystem(string Emotion)
{

    for(int i = 0; i < ParticleSystems.Count; i++)
    {
       if(Emotion == YourEmotions[i])
       {
          StartCoroutine(MyCoroutine(ParticleSystems[i]));
       }
    }

}

IEnumerator MyCoroutine (GameObject ObjectToActivate)
{
    ObjectToActivate.SetActive(True);    
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(activationDuration);
    ObjectToActivate.SetActive(False);
}
```

I am sure there are other ways to do it as well. I don't think any will be extremely straightforward though.